# netbeans c++ googletest run tests from gui

Tags: c++, ubuntu, netbeans, cmake, googletest

So I have NetBeans 8.1 running on ubuntu 14.04. I have an existing project using CMakeLists files as well as googletest. I am trying to set it up and runnig. So I installed the NBCndUnit, and then followed instructions found here: https://github.com/offa/NBCndUnit/wiki/Using-existing-projects#a-workaround-for-cmake. 
here's part of my project/CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0037 OLD)
add_custom_target(build-tests COMMENT "starting build-tests target" )
add_custom_target(test myAppTest COMMENT "starting test target")
```

and here's the part of my myApp/test CMakeLists file:

```
add_executable(myAppTest ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

target_link_libraries(myAppTest 
    -L${GTEST_LIBRARY_DIR} 
    -L${GMOCK_LIBRARY_DIR}
    myApp
    gtest
    gmock
    # other dependencies
)

add_test(myAppTest myAppTest )
```

when I right click on the main project CMakeLists.txt file and choose "generate makefile" - it succeeds. When I then right click on the Makefile and go to Make Target submenu, I can choose several targets:

- all
- clean
- help
- build-tests
- test

When I then choose eg. "build-tests" target - nothing happens (which is expected, as this target is empty):

```
cd '(some project path)/cmake_build'
/usr/bin/make  -f Makefile build-tests
Built target build-tests
```

If i choose "test" target - it gets built and executed (output in the console window)

```
cd '(path to project)/cmake_build'
/usr/bin/make  -f Makefile test
[ 34%] Built target dependency1
[ 54%] Built target dependency2
[ 82%] Built target dependency3
[ 88%] Built target dependency4
[ 97%] Built target dependency5
[100%] starting test target
[==========] Running 111 tests from 7 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from Foo
[ RUN      ] Foo.Bar
[       OK ] Foo.Bar (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from Foo (0 ms total)
(rest of gtest output)
```

But I would like to see the test results in Netbeans TestResults window pane. So I go to the 'Run'->'Test project' command in the menu. And here a problem appears: A new tab is added to the Output pane, it is titled myApp(Build, Build Tests...). And it tries to build the whole project:

```
cd '(project path)/cmake_build'
/usr/bin/make -j4 -f Makefile
```

the problem is, that the whole project is not yet buildable, due to dependencies. All that is necessary is mocked in the myAppTest (and the test themselves are runable - eg. by building the "test" target from makefile context menu). So the real question is:
Can I somehow skip building whole project before bulding and running the actual tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, i was partially able to sovle my problem. what i did, is to add custom project properties configuration scheme:
[image]

I simply added some fake build target (`build_tests`), so NB builds it instead of the default `all` target. Kind of hacky, but does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I somehow skip building whole project before bulding and running the actual tests?

Netbeans builds `all` targets by default. This is somehow integrated I guess. One think you can try is to exclude the objects / targets from this default target.

Another way to go: Add an option which (eg. `BUILD_TESTS_ONLY`) which builds only the parts needed to run the tests. This option can be off by default so it doesn't break any other builds.